# Tikz: two edge path

Tags: latex, tikz

Can I use \path to draw a line that goes through 2 edges.

Consider:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\tikzstyle{status} = [rectangle, draw=black, text centered, anchor=north, text=black, minimum width=2em, minimum height=2em, node distance=6ex and 7em, font=\bfseries]
\tikzstyle{line} = [draw,thick,-latex]
\tikzstyle{transition} = [font=\small]

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node [status, fill=green] (T) {H};
    \node [status, fill=red, right=4em of T] (A) {A};
    \node [status, fill=gray, right=4em of A] (D) {D};

    \path [line] (T) -- (A) node[transition,pos=0.5,above,align=left] {$\#A \geq 1$};
    \path [line] (A) -- (D) node[transition,pos=0.5,above,align=left] {wait $\tau$ tick\\$\tau\sim\mathcal{G}(\lambda)$};
    %\path [line] (D) -| (T) node[transition,pos=0.83,left] {$p_{repl}$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

Mockup of what I want:

[image: mockup]

Comment: Just noticed I duplicated it, sorry! http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/252241/tikz-two-edges-path-connection

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easier than we thought, you can make it substituting the commented line (line number 17) in your code with:

```
\path [line] (D) -- ++(0,-1) -- +(-4.25,0) -- (T) node[transition,pos=0.3,right] {$p_{repl}$};
```

The output:

[image: screenshot of the output pdf]

**Improvement:** even better, using `-|` and then one aux point only instead of two (one is needed):

```
\path [line] (D) -- ++(0,-1) -| (T) node [transition,pos=0.8,left] {$p_{repl}$};
```